# Problem while using find method of Find Module in Ruby 1.9.2

Tags: ruby, find, errno

I am writing the following code in irb in my windows terminal having **ruby-1.9.2**...
and even though the code is just using the find function of the module Find, I am encountering the following error:

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'find'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> Find.find("") do |f|
irb(main):003:1* p f.to_s
irb(main):004:1> end
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/find.rb:38:in `block in find'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/find.rb:38:in `collect!'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/find.rb:38:in `find'
        from (irb):2
        from C:/Ruby192/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

I have also tried the above code in a file(.rb) but am encountering the same error.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing an empty string to the `.find` method. You're supposed to pass the paths you want to traverse as an argument, for example `Find.find("/tmp") do |f|`.

See [the Find module's documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/find/rdoc/index.html) for an example.

Comment: I have tried using this also where path = Pathname.getwd, Find.find("","#{path}") { |f| p f.to_s } but the error persists

Comment: Because with that code, you still have an empty string as a parameter. Just try `Find.find(path) { |f| p f.to_s }`.

Comment: Yes its working now.. Thanks for your help.. Actually a few days back I had used the same code with Ruby-1.9.1 and it worked but now it was giving errors that's why I thought it a bug...